# how to query an array of objects in a document firestore? i want to get an object with specific id init

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a collection of users and document contain array of objects, array name is employee I want to filter employee on a single value like id, is it possible to achieve that?

```
collection: users

Document: J9rsXaepXMMNGUXPhpnKuDr

fields: employee[{name: ross, age: 24, id: 237878},{name: peter, age: 30, id: 887878}]

 const citiesRef = collection(db, 'user');

      const q = query(citiesRef, where('employee', 'array-contains', {id: '887878'}));

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
     
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and show us what exactly would you like to query.

Comment: i don't have 10 reputation on the site, so image is not uploading however i typed schema above hope it helps you understand the question, sorry for late reply